# Implicit type conversion of return value

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I have a function which returns a long but the value which I return is an integer. I know about implicit casting but technically the function return type doesn't match the return value's type. The code compiles and runs without warnings or errors. What is happening here?

```cs
public static long GetIndex(int Index){
  int [] marks = new int[5]  {99, 98, 92, 97, 95};
  return marks[Index];
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  long n = GetIndex(3);
}
```

Comment: boxing/unboxing. Change `int []marks` to `long [] marks = new long[]`

Comment: @michasaucer: There's no boxing or unboxing going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the return statement will apply implicit conversions. Here's a simple example:

```cs
public long Method()
{
    int value = 10;
    return value;
}
```

This is just equivalent to:

```cs
public long Method()
{
    int value = 10;
    long valueToReturn = value;
    return valueToReturn;
}
```

So if you'd expect the second one to work, just think of the first as doing exactly that.

Comment: Thanks, we were thinking the conversion has to be done but it seems a bit dangerous. Will the return statement try to cast for all types? `public static object getIndex(int Index)`

Comment: @JoshSharkey: It will do exactly the same implicit conversions that a variable assignment would do. Yes, that would include boxing, if you returned `object`. (As an aside, I'd strongly recommend following .NET naming conventions even for method names in samples.) There's nothing dangerous here, unless you also count the conversion in the second example in my answer as dangerous. What kind of danger are you thinking of?

Comment: if the return statement cant make the conversion would there be an error thrown?

Comment: @JoshSharkey: It's simplest just to try :) But it'll be a compile-time error, just like an assignment to an incompatible variable would be. You can think of the `return` statement as if it's assigning to a variable.